# Does the Debian python3-opencv package have advantages over the pypy.org opencv-python one?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, debian, pypi

Under Debian I can install the OpenCV bindings for Python using (at least) one of these two ways:

- from the [Debian repository](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/python3-opencv) (with `apt install python3-opencv`)
- or from the [PyPI repository](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) (with `pip install opencv-python`)

Does the Debian package have any advantages over the PyPI package? For example, does it use better CPU optimizations, i.e. is it faster?

Or is there some recommendation by the OpenCV developers regarding this choice?

Background for this question is that I'm currently using the Debian package, but I'd prefer to switch to the PyPI package for easier maintenance; but I don't want to loose performance or miss other improvements by doing that change.

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734792/difference-between-installing-a-package-with-apt-and-pip

Comment: short answer: no. answer depends on who you ask. if you ask the linux people, they'll tell you to use apt. if you ask the opencv people, they'll tell you to use pip. why? the apt package might lag behind in releases because it's not maintained by opencv. if you're worried about performance, compare them on your system.

Comment: the ***official*** `opencv-python` package on PyPI contains IPP. there is no benefit to using third-party maintained packages such as those maintained by debian. in fact, they don't provide packages of recent releases of OpenCV. we are at v4.8.1 and debian offers 4.6.0, which is from mid 2022.

Comment: @DerSchinken: thanks for the link; but that only answers the _general_ APT-vs-PIP question. I am interested in differences in the opencv-python packages in particular, though.

Comment: @oliver I mean yes you can never be sure, but it's very unlikely that the docs wouldn't tell you about it, so it's probably just the reasons mentioned in the questions answers